# What is wrong with my nghttp2.conf backend pattern?

Tags: nghttp2

Here is my `nghttpx.conf` file:

```
frontend=0.0.0.0,3000
backend=127.0.0.0,9901;;proto=h2
frontend-no-tls=yes
backend-no-tls=yes
workers=1
log-level=INFO
```

When I do:

```
sudo nghttpx
```

This error is thrown:

```
28/Nov/2017:15:33:30 +0900 PID19518 [ERROR] shrpx_config.cc:1418 backend: ';' must not be used in pattern
28/Nov/2017:15:33:30 +0900 PID19518 [FATAL] shrpx.cc:1714 Failed to load configuration from /etc/nghttpx/nghttpx.conf
```

What is wrong with my nghttpx config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/nghttpx.1.html) page of `nghttpx` we see that `--backend` option supports the following structure:

> `--backend=(<HOST>,<PORT>|unix:<PATH>)[;[<PATTERN>[:...]][[;<PARAM>]...]`

Since you have `backend=127.0.0.0,9901;<PATTERN>`, everything that follows `;` should be a valid `<PATTERN>`. Upon further reading of the manual we see that it says:

> Since ";" and ":" are  used as  delimiter,    must  not contain  these characters. Since  ";" has  special meaning in shell, the option value must be quoted.

Now, looking at your error, it says:

> shrpx_config.cc:1418 backend: ';' must not be used in pattern

Which indicates that you have used `;` in a pattern, which is not allowed. This agrees with the manual excerpt above.

So it seems that your issue is that you have one too many `;` characters in your pattern. At the moment it is `;proto=h2`, when it should be `proto=h2`. Try removing the redundant `;` (i.e. it should read `backend=127.0.0.0,9901;proto=h2`) and see if that helps with the error you're getting.